# Cannot retrieve data from facebook but apps running fine

Tags: android, facebook

```
i was following the tutorial from facebook developer website to retrieve my profile name and show in apps but it is just return nothing but the word that i input myself in else condition. I had generate the android key hashes from my computer and put to my fb developer profile and the apps id had include in my android project as well....

package com.example.mobile_e_commerce;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

public class SignInPage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_page);
```

This is to open the facebook login

```
         // start Facebook Login
          Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

              // callback when session changes state

            @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
```

the session should be opened i think but no///

```
                if (session.isOpened()) {

                  // make request to the /me API
                  Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                      if (user != null) {
```

The user should be my name, so it should output Hello Issac but return the else condition statement!

```
                        TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                        welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }
                else
                {
                        TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                        welcome.setText("User = Null");
                }
              }
            });
          /*
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }*/
    }
```

to get the response from facebook activity

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

this part is just general android code

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sign_in_page, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

this part is just general android code

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

this part is just general android code

```
    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
```

this part is just general android code

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in_page,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using last facebook sdk  and reading more in facebook graph api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/

Comment: I just found out that the facebook session is not open somehow///do u have any idea???

Comment: try using UI helper like in facebook login example

Comment: It solved now and it is only because of the wrong android key hashes generate from an expired debug.keystore

Comment: ok, so let write that in a different answer and accept it for other users who get the same problem. look on my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because you are using the wrong key hash.

You should generate new hash key and use it instead of what you have now.